# SQL Server Agent Job for SSRS subscription loses schedule config

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, sql-server-2014

We have a series of subscriptions on SSRS that email out reports in Excel format every 30 minutes. I have edited these via SQL Server Agent in Management Studio so the schedule only runs between certain times on weekdays only - as I don't believe this is possible via SSRS.

One particular subscription, a couple of times a day, reverts back to running once per week at 8:00 on Mondays. I then have to edit the schedule again. No errors occur and it does work for a few hours at a time.

I imagine it's related to me editing the schedule via the 'back-end' but all the other similar subscriptions where I have done the same work fine.

Can anybody suggest where I should be looking to investigate this? What other detail would be useful to help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you the only person who can edit the schedule?

Comment: It prompted me to investigate when the schedule was actually being changed - turns out it's at 2:10 every morning which suggests there's a job out there affecting it. I've got the DBA checking for jobs running at this time.